# Submit selected items of ListView in Request (used in Webpart)

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, client-object-model, list-view

I develop a WebPart using VS2010 for a SharePoint page.
My problem: I have to submit the selected items of the ListView to the WebPart code behind. The best solution would be to do it via the Request or Requestheaders. For this I use the ClientObjectModel in a script embedded in the ascx file of my WebPart.

code:

```
<SharePoint:ListView runat="server" ID="listViewTechnologies" />
...some other html here...
    <script type="text/C#">
            var itemsArray = new Array();
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            this.web = ctx.get_web();
            ctx.load(this.web);
            this.currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(listViewTechnologies);
            ctx.load(currentLib);
            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
            var item;
            for (item in selectedItems) {
                var id = selectedItems[item].id;
                var Listitem = currentLib.getItemById(id);
                this.itemsArray[this.itemsArray.length] = Listitem;
                ctx.load(Listitem);
// code to add my items to the Request?!
            }

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess),
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailed));

            function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
                for (i = 0; i < this.itemsArray.length; i++) {
                    var item = this.itemsArray[i];
// code to add my items to the Request?!
                }
            }
    </script>
```

How could I add my items in the Request now?

Solution:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnAdd" ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/CALADD.GIF" OnClientClick="ibtnAdd_OnClientClick()" ToolTip="Technologien hinzufügen" />
...some other html here...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ibtnAdd_OnClientClick() {
            var selectedItems = ctx.dictSel;
            var itemIds = '';
            var currentItem;
            var containsItems = false;
            for (currentItem in selectedItems) {
                itemIds += selectedItems[currentItem].id + ",";
                if (!containsItems) {
                    containsItems = true;
                }
            }
            if (containsItems) {
                // trim trailing ',' from end
                itemIds = itemIds.substring(0, itemIds.length - 1);
                __doPostBack("ibtnAdd", itemIds);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I will post the working code, when it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript `__dopostback` for this

```
__doPostBack('RibbonDemo', itemIds + ";" + listId);
```

In the page load event you can read the items

```
if (this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "RibbonDemo")
{
    string parameter = this.Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    int index = parameter.IndexOf(';');
    string listID = parameter.Substring(index + 1);
    string itemIds = parameter.Substring(0, index);
    string[] itemIdArray = itemIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Further code implementation
}
```

For more information you can refer:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/07/invoke-server-side-code-on-sharepoint_14.html

Comment: At the moment I don't have a custom ribbon and for my purposes this would be a little bit overpowered.
The other problem would occure when I use js: I don't know wether the code to read out these ListItems would still work.

Comment: What I mean to say here is that after you are done reading your list items, you can force the page postback using __dopostback and read the items in the page load of the webpart control. You don't have to do anything with ribbon. Since I had written the blog post I simply copied it from there.

Comment: Perfectly, I tried something and now nearly works. The suggestion with the doPostback method is the perfect solution. Thanks a lot.